# Object search in android instead of list of strings for a listview

Tags: android, list, listview, search, autocomplete

When I give the list of strings from object to adapter it only searches those names in the list and displays them( I need total object to be searched).

But it shows a separate view like dropdown menu, but I need to show them like this
[image: Search view]

When I type a letter it fetches all words and shows them in the dropdown layout instead of that I need it to be done like above figure.

To display them in the drop down I used this code

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
String[] cities= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities_array);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**But how to high lite a word directly in the listview as show in the figure**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `SpannableString` if you just want to style the text

Here's a util function I use in some of my apps to set the color of the text, you could modify it by changing it to a `BackgroundColorSpan`

If you want to do something exactly like in the picture with a drawable (rounded green shape with a drop shadow, you might be able to use a `DynamicDrawableSpan`.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan.html

```
/** 
 * Taken with permission from PocketPermissions, this method is licensed under Apache 2.0
 * Sets two colors in a single TextView or Button.
 */
public static void setTwoColorsTextStrings( String str1, String str2, TextView tv, Context c, int color1, int color2 )
{           
    SpannableString spnstr1 = new SpannableString( str1 );
    SpannableString spnstr2 = new SpannableString( str2 );

    int start = 0;
    int len = str1.length();

    int start2 = 0;
    int len2 = str2.length();

    spnstr1.setSpan( new ForegroundColorSpan( color1 ), start, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );           
    spnstr2.setSpan( new ForegroundColorSpan( color2 ), start2, len2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );

    SpannableString fullString = SpannableString.valueOf( TextUtils.concat( spnstr1,  spnstr2 ) );

    tv.setText( fullString, BufferType.SPANNABLE );         
}
```

Comment: I also need text to be highlited but before that , If i search for a word then how to higlite it and for this I need a code. Here I should get more than single word.

Comment: Ah I see, you may have to override the Adapter then and format it in `getView()`